# How to make a header showing with out the vertical scroll bar?

Tags: css, html

I know this is sometimes foolish or wired question which has no effort.

I want a header without the vertical scroll-bar.
As shown in the figure: This is the home page design and i need the top yellow header strip to be shown without the vertical scroll bar like image 2

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

I tried many css hack and ended up into some problems to the existing design.How can i make it possible?

Comment: make wrapper for content and give him scroll flow, instead of full body scrolling. Also without html/css nobody will give you solution for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fady has the right idea, sort of...

So, the header here appears to be separate from the content that has the scrollbar.

General idea.

```
--- Header width Fixed Height
 |
 |
--- Main Content - with a set height and overflow-y set to auto.
```

Actually written out, it's something along these lines:

html

```
<header>Header Content here</header>
<main>Main Content here</main>
```

css

```
header {
  height: 50px;
}
main {
  height:500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the overflow of the wraper container to overflow hidden like this :

> overflow-y: hidden;